# IPv4 addressing (network address and broadcast adddress)

Tags: networking, ipv4, subnet

I know this might not be the best place for this sort of question but i'm afraid I don't have much time my exam is coming up. Let's say in a network with a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0, what address is considered the network address and what address is considered broadcast. I know for example in a class C network with a default subnet mask (255.255.255.0), and a netowrk IP of 192.168.1.0, the broadcast is 192.168.1.255, but this is self explanatory since there is only one octet for the host portion. So my question is in a class B network or a class A network with a default subnet mask, what would be the legal addresses (which addresses are the host and broadcast)

Thank you in advance <3

Comment: The network classes have been deprecated for many years. It's all `CIDR` now.

Comment: [See this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) about IPv4 addressing and IPv4 math. By the way, network address classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years before the commercial Internet in 1995) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). We have not used network address classes in this century.

Comment: I did not realise classes were dead, I guess we are learning them since this is still the beginning and the introduction of the course. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best place for this question would be https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com but here it goes:

The broadcast address is the network IP with all host bits set to 1.

So for 192.168.0.0/16 (mask 255.255.0.0) it would be 192.168.255.255,

for 192.0.0.0/8 (mask 255.0.0.0) it would be 192.255.255.255,

for 192.64.0.0/10 (mask 255.192.0.0) it would be 192.127.255.255 and so on.

Comment: While your answer is technically correct for CIDR, the question was about network classes, and in the old classful networking `192.168.0.0/16` is still Class C , as is `192.0.0.0/8`. The network classes were defined by the first bits of the address, not the mask size. Your answer would be more accurate for the question if you used `172.16.0.0/16` and `10.0.0.0/8` for the Class B and A (respectively). Also, `10.64.0.0/10` instead of `192.64.0.0/10` as a subnet of Class A..

Comment: @Anton thank you for both the answer and for the URL <3